# Comparing 2 very large arraylists in java

Tags: java, arraylist, out-of-memory

What would be the correct approach when you need to compare 2 very large arraylists with each other?

These arraylist are both 100,000 items in size and will definitely crash when simply comparing item per item.

```
for (CItem c : cItems) {
        for (CItem r : rItems) {
            if (c.getID().equals(r.getID())) {
                Mismatch m = compareItems(c, r);
                if (m != null) {
                    mismatches.add(m);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I'm not 100% sure how the garbage collection works in this situation but the errors we get are:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:407) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
```

and

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:261) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:235) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:227) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:458) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
```

So far the possible solutions are

- Split each list into a maximum of x items and compare these multiple lists (kind of elaborate)
- Create a new database and query every item (which would be very slow and not feasable right now)
- Buy 200 gb of ram

Any input on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: the issue is not with your compare, but adding to a new ArrayList when finding a mismatch

Comment: what is compareItems(c, r) ?

Comment: What output from the comparison do you want?

Comment: Have you increased your heap size? No idea how big your objects are, but a couple of 100,000 items doesn't sound *that* big?

Comment: I will suggest to create a new query and find the difference directly.

Comment: Can you just try to print that how many items added before exception?

Comment: How many items with the same id can be in one of the lists? Also the nested loop approach looks pretty expensive, how about sorting the lists by id and then iterating over both of them in one go?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Is the adding to the new list causing the issues? >Siddharth compareItems compares the 2 objects (has about 40 properties). >Tim the output is the same object as the two inputs. >Robby increasing heap size does nothing. >JavaGeo the db is very large and not optimized at all. >Piet could you elaborate on that cause it sounds quite promising

Comment: 200000 items isn't the problem. `100000*100000` is.

Comment: There is a check in place so no 2 objects with the same ID get added multiple times

Comment: Try to use LinkedList for mismatches

Comment: [1,2,3,4,5,1] and [1,3,1,5,1] ... is it possible input? if yes, then what do you expect in output.
if not, then provide some sample input lists and output list.

Comment: The first stack trace shows String allocation, so some code called from your inner loop is creating lots of strings. The list size might be a red herring. Get a memory profile to see what's taking the space. We're all just guessing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the IDs in any item-list are unique, you can use a `Map` for your `rItems` with the `ID` as key.

```
Map<Long, CItem> rItemMap = new HashMap<>(rItems.size());
for (CItem r : rItems) {
    rItemMap.put(r.getID(), r);
}
```

Now you can check directly for rItems with same ID:

```
for (CItem c : cItems) {
    CItem r = rItemMap.get(c.getID());
    if (r != null) {
        Mismatch m = compareItems(c, r);
        if (m != null) {
            mismatches.add(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Even if the IDs are not unique, you could still work with a Map, you just would have a List of all items with that ID as the value of one Map.Entry and you'd only have to iterate over those few items instead of iterating over the whole list.

**Edit regarding OutOfMemory**

I just saw from your Exception, that you're using `ArrayList`. Using `LinkedList` instead might help, because the ArrayList is based on a (fixed size) array and when that array is filled up, a new - larger - array is allocated and the data from the old array is copied to the new array and then freed.

So if you have an array of size 1000 and it is full, a new array of e.g. size 2000 is allocated. At that moment, memory for 3000 items is required (although the 1000 are freed shortly after).

A LinkedList just allocates memory for every item you add to it (plus memory to point to the next and previous element).

Comment: Sounds interesting, will definitely try this

Comment: Works great and is pretty fast, unfortunately I discovered that that the recordset containing 100,000 rows also crashes. That can't be solved by a hashmap unfortunately..

Comment: Try using LinkedList instead of ArrayList - see my edited answer

Comment: @Ridcully Using LinkedList is unlikely to help. It has *six times* the per-element overhead of ArrayList, so you'd run out of space with LL sooner than you would with AL, even accounting for AL's transient memory usage during resizing.

Comment: @woodsprite See previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

It looks you want to see if 2 objects with the same ID are the same when compared an other way.

Probable Problem here is that you check 100.000 x 100.000 objects against each other. To make it worse, you just add the ones to a new list...

Option **1)** You did not tell how you created the ArrayList()s. If you get the objects from a Database you might just query that. (those are good at that, even if you aren't)

Option **2)** Add the 2 ArrayList()s together, they seem to be the same kind of objects. Make the objects sortable (maybe by ID), sort the single list. (creates an other problem) Then use a loop to compare the now sorted Objects to their neighbour.

Comment: The database is very large and terribly optimized, querying it for single items will not work (also not allowed right now). The arraylists are created by querying a view. Option 2 sounds promising though, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method **removeAll** in the collection interface :)

```
rItems.removeAll(cItems);
```

if you look inside of the implementtion, the method compares using equals aswell...

This approach would let you obtain the items from each list which do not match to the other one.

Comment: Interesting but not possible as no 2 objects will ever be exactly the same, unfortunately

Comment: @woorsprite can you not implement equals for those items based on `compareItems()`? or, if not, a comparator for the collection?

Answer (score 1):

Sort the 2 lists and then compare them in order. Sorting costs `O(n log n)` and compare costs `O(n)`.

```
Comparator<CItem> idComparator = new Comparator<CItem>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(CItem i1, CItem i2) {
        // Implementation depends on the type of CItem ID:
        // if ID is an integer or double, maybe you need
        // return i1.getID() - i2.getID();
        return i1.getID().compareTo(i2.getID());
    }
});

Collections.sort(cItems, idComparator);
Collections.sort(rItems, idComparator);

int minLen = Math.min(cItems.size(), rItems.size());
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < minLen && j < minLen; ) {

    CItem c = cItems.get(i);
    CItem r = rItems.get(j);

    // c.getID().equals(r.getID())
    if (idComparator.compare(c, r) == 0) {
        Mismatch m = compareItems(c, r);
        if (m != null) {
            mismatches.add(m);
        }
        i++;
        j++;

    // item c's ID does not exist in list rItems
    } else if (idComparator.compare(c, r) < 0) {
        i++;

    // item r's ID does not exist in list cItems
    } else {
        j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. So I tried to use LinkedList.
So I have 2 Linkedlist that can contain up to 3.5millions of string records.
And then I am running

```
LinkedList diflist= (LinkedList) ListUtils.subtract(sourceList, targetList);
```

to get the difference,but my application stacks on this.

So are there any good algorithms to compare lists?

Comment: You've posted this as an answer, but you've basically re-asked your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723028/how-to-compare-two-huge-liststring-in-java . That's probably because somebody closed your question as a duplicate of this one. But I don't think they're actually the same problems. I've reopened your question; please respond to the comments there. Thanks!