# JUnit AssertEquals truncates array results

Tags: java, junit, junit4

In my headless system, I'm looking to check for content equality of two generic types (e.g `T`) with the `assertThat(generic1).isEqualTo(generic2)` function in JUnit4.

A minimally reproducible example can be made by defining two generic variables and calling the `isEqualTo` method on them, where `T` is a Java Generic type, and the function `returnArrayListGeneric()` has a return type of T, which ***could*** be an ArrayList:

```
T a = returnArrayListGeneric();
T b = returnArrayListGeneric();

assertThat(a).isEqualTo(b)
```

This works when T is some simple generic types, but with a very long array, JUnit automatically truncates the printed content of the Arrays to 30 elements long, which makes it impossible to examine the difference between the ArrayLists past that point. Example below:

```
Expecting:
 <"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, ... (199970 more)] (ArrayList@7bde3f35)">
to be equal to:
 <"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, ... (199970 more)] (ArrayList@c67be61)">
but was not.
```

Since this is a headless system, I don't believe that I have access to setting variables such as `idea.junit....`, neither do I have access to GUI-based debuggers.

I have attempted augmenting the test method itself to print out the content of the arrays manually. But since the arguments themselves are generics and cannot be directly casted to an `ArrayList<Integer>`, and I do not wish to modify the implementation of the classes and methods themselves, I am currently stuck on that as well.

Any input  would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The message says `199970 more` so it is unrealistic to think any one person can go through the whole sequence, that is why it makes sense JUnit would truncate it. Alternatively, if you care about the exact difference between these two lists, check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/41723028/2453382 and it's corresponding answers.

Comment: I am also curious as to why would you need to compare two large generics AND care about their members? Should it not be enough to know that they are not the same? What was the motivation behind this test? Usually complicated problems come with systemic issues, you can consider a refactor as well.

Comment: Every class has `toString`, so I'm not sure why the members of the Lists being of an unknown class is an obstacle to printing them?

Comment: Incidentally you can connect a debugger to a JVM remotely, so you can use a GUI debugger, as long as you can get access to a socket.

Comment: Are you using AssertJ? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which shows the problem you have and how you use the generic types. Is it an option to use `assertThatList()`?

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback! I've added an example & will investigate the directions above.